# Calculation of two dimensional Fourier transform on a disk using FFT?

Tags: numerical-methods

How to calculate the FFT of the function $f(x,y)$ defined on a disk ($\sqrt{x^2+y^2}<r$)?

It seems all published FFT code deal with 2-dimensional Fourier transform for functions defined on rectangular areas. Can the existing code, by some modification, be used to compute the FFT of functions on a disk?

Answer (score 0):

You would have to define first what the DFT on a disk is. The DFT can in general be defined for any group of translations. Take the group defined by two translation vectors in the plane and you get the DFT on the torus or unwrapped a rectangle or parallelogram.

I don't see a similar group action for the circle.